# How to make masonry element fit perfectly and full whole width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-isotope, masonry

I have an element that uses [the masonry code from here](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

What I want is the following layout: [image]

All images fit perfectly, and the entire element fits the whole page.

What I currently got myself (all images are exactly the same size as in the example shown above):

[image]

My element is build like this:

```
<div id="gallery-items" class="gallery-items wow fadeInUp animated" data-wow-duration="2s" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 2s; animation-name: fadeInUp; position: relative; height: 571px;">
    <figure class="gallery-item masonryfullwidth" style="border: 1px solid blue; position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 0px;">
        <img src="cms/images/masonry/print/k1.jpg" class="imagemasonry" alt="gallery">
        <figcaption>
          <a class="fancybox" href="cms/images/masonry/print/k1.jpg">
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-plus"></span>
          </a>
          <a href="#fakelink">
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-info"></span>
          </a>
        </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure class="gallery-item masonryfullwidth" style="border: 1px solid blue; position: absolute; left: 10.1944%; top: 0px;">
        <img src="cms/images/masonry/print/k10.jpg" class="imagemasonry" alt="gallery">
        <figcaption>
          <a class="fancybox" href="cms/images/masonry/print/k10.jpg">
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-plus"></span>
          </a>
          <a href="#fakelink">
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-info"></span>
          </a>
        </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure class="gallery-item masonryfullwidth" style="border: 1px solid blue; position: absolute; left: 30.5833%; top: 0px;">
        <img src="cms/images/masonry/print/k100.jpg" class="imagemasonry" alt="gallery">
        <figcaption>
          <a class="fancybox" href="cms/images/masonry/print/k100.jpg">
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-plus"></span>
          </a>
          <a href="#fakelink">
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-info"></span>
          </a>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

Then in my footer I got the following part inside a document ready function:

```
var $container = $('#gallery-items');

  $(window).load(function() {
      $container.isotope({
          //resizable: false, // disable normal resizing
          transitionDuration: '0.65s',
          masonry: {
              columnWidth: $container.find('.gallery-item:not(.wide)')[0]
          }
      });

      $(window).resize(function() {
          $container.isotope('layout');
      });
  });
```

In my example when I resize the window the images get resized to fit their parentdiv, but my masonry elements all stay the same size even when resizing.

You can see the masonry I made [here](https://studionewmedia.nl/reclame/groot_formaat_printen.html)

Comment: hello do you need the gallery always be in the same amount of rows and columns and not be reordered while window is resized ?  (everything scaled down or up )

Comment: @G-Cyr I already got it to work, thanks.

Comment: okay, if you are curious about display grid https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/rGYzLd .

Comment: @G-Cyr Yeah thanks that it how I wanted it, I noticed I missed a small block to fill the last gap.